# What version of Ankh should i choose for TortoiseSVN 1.6.7, Build 18415 - 64 Bit?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

What version of Ankh should i choose for Visual Studio 2010 and TortoiseSVN 1.6.7, Build 18415 - 64 Bit

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the newest version of AnkhSVN, that would be Version 2.1 at the moment.

AnkhSVN is a *standalone* subversion client that is completely independent of TortoiseSVN.

If you are looking for a Visual Studio add-in, that is using TortoiseSVN, use VSTortoise:
https://vstortoise.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

AnkhSVN 2.3.11269 (and maybe other versions) is "dependent" on TortoiseSVN (=Subversion client) / **working copy format** version.

Just got this message after installing/using **AnkhSVN 2.3.11269**:

Subversion detected a working copy that needs an explicit upgrade in '...'.

While this working copy is not upgraded all files in this working copy will appear as new.

When a working copy is upgraded it can no longer used by Subversion clients that weren't designed for this (or later) working copy formats.

So I gave **VsTortoise** a try since it still supports **Subversion 1.6** --> **VsTortoise** is a "normal" VS plug-in not a "SCC provider". It just adds TortoiseSVN commands to VS. TortoiseSVN seems to be mandatory anyway! It is just a lightway alternative to AnkhSVN but does not support e.g. moving files on the client/working copy.